# Firefox cannot save Adobe Flash Player settings

Tags: 13.04, firefox, flash, adobe, opera

When I visit a Flash based site the Flash Player tab pop-ups, as usual. Everyone knows that is not working (under Unity), so I tried to set things on Adobe's site. The only problem is that the Flash cannot save my settings. [I tried to edit things, blocking/denying sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6PUw.jpg), increase/decrease/delete cache, but it did not make the change. It looks like I have no permission to edit these settings or something like that. But it worked before. Everything is up-to-date (Flash version: 11.2.202.297).

How can I find out the reason or edit manually these settings?

**UPDATE**: I tested it with Opera too and the result is the same, so both browsers cannot save these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit Flash settings [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html).

It should help :)

Comment: I already did that one. I linked a picture too above.